# Repairing login loop, new install, data recovery

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, login

I got a "login loop" with my 18.04 install. Nothing worked to remedy, used 20.04 DVD. No "repair" option, tried to "install beside current" to preserve data. 20.04 works great, but now I have 3 "volumes" I can't access. They take up all available HDD space on the dual boot. Can't install anything like ecryptfs, "no space". 3 volumes of different sizes, one just 26 GB and a Windows partition.

Want to recover some family videos from old installation and passwords/logins from old Pale Moon install.

Tried Testdisk, didn't do anything.

Comment: Boot from the same version of Ubuntu that owns the hard drive partitions.

Comment: Would not even boot. Tried from USB. Will try another DVD of U 18.

Comment: Are these inaccessable volumes encrypted? If so, say so clearly in your question -- it's important.

Comment: Not encrypted. They are sitting on Ubuntu desktop, taking ALL HDD space, but every file says "contains 0 items/bytes". Can't access "access your private data" in the "home" folder of the one volume and root gives me "permission denied". Another volume has only "recycle bin" and "sys volume info" with "indexer volume guid" I can't even play a video on the browser because no available HDD space.

Comment: Did Windows turn fast start up back on? Then you can only manually mount read/only until you directly boot Windows and turn it off. This will not fix anything, but report will show lots of details and may tell us something useful. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Can't update after adding the repository, no space left on HDD, stuck on botched update. I am typing from the same computer.

Comment: Hi, I am working from Windows. My Ubuntu shut down seconds after that last post. Fast start on the Win installation is and was shut off. Ubuntu no longer boots, just displays "clean xxx out of xxx files"